# Swiftmailer/gmail failed to authenticate with username using 2 possible authenticators

Tags: symfony, smtp, gmail, swiftmailer

Scenario: I have a Symfony 3.3 website that needs to send outgoing emails to a particular email address once a contact form is successfully filled out and submitted.   After fighting with sendmail DNS issues (which you can see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/866159/sendmail-connection-refused-by-mail-example-com-when-attempting-to-send-emails)), I decided to change tactics and use Gmail's SMTP server to send the mail.  However, upon flushing the spool, I get the following error:

> 15:04:31 ERROR     [console] Error thrown while running command "swiftmailer:spool:send --env=prod". Message: "Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "user@example.com" using 2 possible authenticators" ["error" => Swift_TransportException { …},"command" => "swiftmailer:spool:send --env=prod","message" => "Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "user@example.com" using 2 possible authenticators"] []
>   15:04:31 ERROR     [console] Command "swiftmailer:spool:send --env=prod" exited with code "1" ["command" => "swiftmailer:spool:send --env=prod","code" => 1] []

My `config.yml`:

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    port: '%mailer_port%'
    encryption: '%mailer_encryption%'
    spool:
        type: file
        path: '%kernel.cache_dir%/swiftmailer/spool'
```

And `parameters.yml`:

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 'smtp.gmail.com'
mailer_user: 'user@example.com'
mailer_password: 'somesecurepassword'
mailer_port: 587
mailer_encryption: 'tls'
```

Do I need to do anything to set tls up on my end, outside of opening the correct port?  Or is there something else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
mailer_transport: gmail
mailer_host: 'smtp.gmail.com'
mailer_user: 'user@example.com'
mailer_password: 'somesecurepassword'
```